# Set google translate don't translate name

Tags: google-translate

I using google translate to translate the entire of my site. but i want Google don't translate some name. Example on this link. http://ulundanu.gusdecool.com/facilities/restaurants

There is name **“Ulun Danu Restaurant”**, when we translate it into Indonesia. It change into **"Pura Ulun Danu Restaurant"**. I want google didn't translate that part. How to do that?

maybe is there some option put some class on it to make google understand not translate that part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add `class="notranslate"` to any HTML element to prevent that element from being translated.

`<span class="notranslate">Ulun Danu Restaurant<span>`

[Google Translate Help-Preventing translation of your webpages](http://support.google.com/translate/?hl=en)