# How can i transtale name, address text in english language without changing the pronunciation in GCP translate api using python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I a trying to translate name of person and address from Indian language to English. I want to keep the pronunciation intact. for example "सौरव" needs to change to "sourab". Is there a parameter in google translate using python to do this. There are some html prameter but is there something for python.
[Set google translate don't translate name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786907/set-google-translate-dont-translate-name)

```
     from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
        
def translate_text_with_model(target, text, model="nmt"):
        
        translate_client = translate.Client()
    
        if isinstance(text, six.binary_type):
            text = text.decode("utf-8")
    
        result = translate_client.translate(text, target_language=target, model=model)
    
        print(u"Translation: {}".format(result["translatedText"]))
```

translate_text_with_model("en", "23 राज्सव", model="nmt")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sourav. I was able to replicate the issue, when running your code the result was:

```
Translation: 23 Revenue
```

When the expected output is for "राज्सव" to be translated as a noun "Sourav".

In this instance, since you are dealing with Proper nouns or names, I suggest you create a glossary of words so that the API can use the preset values of the glossary instead of translating the words. You can read the documentation for glossaries and their implementation [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#format-glossary)

Here is the code and glossary I created to obtain the expected output.

`glossary.csv` (This file must be uploaded in a Google Cloud Storage bucket)

```
hi,en,pos,description
राज्सव,Sourav,noun,Name of user
```

[Note that each new row represents another word you would like to override with your glossary and you can also add more language columns](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#equivalent_term_sets_csv).

`create_glossary.py` (YOUR_GLOSSARY_ID is any identifier you will use to run text through your glossary)

```
from google.cloud import translate_v3 as translate


def create_glossary(
    project_id="YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
    input_uri="YOUR_INPUT_URI", #gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/glossary.csv
    glossary_id="YOUR_GLOSSARY_ID",
    timeout=180,
):
    """
    Create a equivalent term sets glossary. Glossary can be words or
    short phrases (usually fewer than five words).
    https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#format-glossary
    """
    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

    # Supported language codes: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages
    source_lang_code = "hi"
    target_lang_code = "en"
    location = "us-central1"  # The location of the glossary

    name = client.glossary_path(project_id, location, glossary_id)
    language_codes_set = translate.types.Glossary.LanguageCodesSet(
        language_codes=[source_lang_code, target_lang_code]
    )

    gcs_source = translate.types.GcsSource(input_uri=input_uri)

    input_config = translate.types.GlossaryInputConfig(gcs_source=gcs_source)

    glossary = translate.types.Glossary(
        name=name, language_codes_set=language_codes_set, input_config=input_config
    )

    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"
    # glossary is a custom dictionary Translation API uses
    # to translate the domain-specific terminology.
    operation = client.create_glossary(parent=parent, glossary=glossary)

    result = operation.result(timeout)
    print("Created: {}".format(result.name))
    print("Input Uri: {}".format(result.input_config.gcs_source.input_uri))
    
create_glossary()
```

Finally, to process text using your glossary. You use the following function

```
from google.cloud import translate


def translate_text_with_glossary(
    text="23 राज्सव",
    project_id="YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
    glossary_id="YOUR_GLOSSARY_ID",
):
    """Translates a given text using a glossary."""

    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()
    location = "us-central1"
    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

    glossary = client.glossary_path(
        project_id, "us-central1", glossary_id  # The location of the glossary
    )

    glossary_config = translate.TranslateTextGlossaryConfig(glossary=glossary)

    # Supported language codes: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages
    response = client.translate_text(
        request={
            "contents": [text],
            "target_language_code": "en",
            "source_language_code": "hi",
            "parent": parent,
            "glossary_config": glossary_config,
        }
    )

    print("Translated text: \n")
    for translation in response.glossary_translations:
        print("\t {}".format(translation.translated_text))
        
translate_text_with_glossary()
```

This outputs:

```
Translated text: 
         23 Sourav
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at-lest for Indian language
There is a package called indic-nlp-library. and the process of translating based on pronunciation is called Transliterator

official link http://anoopkunchukuttan.github.io/indic_nlp_library/

```
from indicnlp.transliterate.unicode_transliterate import ItransTransliterator
input_text='आज मौसम अच्छा है। इसलिए हम आज खेल सकते हैं!'

# Transliterate Hindi to Roman
print(ItransTransliterator.to_itrans(input_text, 'hn'))
```

output
"aaja mausama achchaa hai. isalie hama aaja khela sakate hai "